# Comparing 2 base filenames in separate directories in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, files, scripting, directory

I am trying to write a bash script that takes 2 file directories as arguments. It then loops through all the files in the first directory to see if there is a corresponding file in the second directory. If there isn't a file with the same basename then delete that file. Right now this is what I have but it doesn't end up doing anything because it thinks that they are all matches for some reason.

```
echo "$directory1"
echo "$directory2"
for f1 in "$directory1/*"
do
    echo $f1
    match=no
    for f2 in "$directory2/*"
    do
        echo $f2
        name1="$(basename "$f1")"
        name2="$(basename "$f2")"
        if [ "$name1" == "$name2" ]
        then
            match=yes
            break
        fi
    done
    echo "$match"
    if [[ "$match" == no ]]
    then
        rm "$f2"
    fi
done
```

Comment: First of all is there a reason you are not using existing tools like rsync to do this? (See the `--delete` option). Secondly can you provide sample output that we can check?

Comment: Yes, `rsync --delete` would probably be enough here. Your code would not work because `*` is not expanded when quoted.  Also, the inner loop is not necessary, or rather, it should be the outer loop and you should test the basenames against names in the first directory (no second loop needed).

Comment: Another remark: the code shown here does not use arguments. Instead it uses undefined variables `$directory1` and `$directory2`. You would need to replace those with `$1` and `$2` to use arguments passed to the script.

Comment: @Bram `rsync --delete` would force the files in the two directories to be identical.  This is not a requirement from the script given.

Comment: Do you want to delete files of `directory2` that are not found in `directory1` or the reverse?

Comment: Do you want to consider only *regular* files or only *non-directory* files or any file (of *any type*)? What about hidden files?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it, use find to list files in each directory, use basename and sort to order them.  Then feed each list to comm and only print out the files present in the first directory but not the second.  Once the list looks the way you expect it to, you can pipe that to rm.

```
comm -2 -3  <(find "$directory1" -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs -n1 -d\\n basename | sort) <(find "$directory2" -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs -n1 -d\\n basename | sort)  | xargs -d\\n printf "$directory1/%s\n" | xargs -d\\n rm
```

note: as @LeviUzodike pointed out, you wanted to delete files in the first directory not found in the second, so I made the appropriate changes.  I also avoided using the -a argument for basename

Comment: Heads up this doesn't work in CentOS 6 because `basename` has no options. But it does work for CentOS 7. Also nbd, but this solution will delete the mismatching files in `directory2` not `directory1`, which to my understanding, is the opposite of what the OP wanted.

Comment: Hey thanks @LeviUzodike, I've made your suggested changes above.  I didn't realize the -a argument is not supported in RHEL6, good to know :).

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier with `zsh` and its `${array1:|array2}` array subtraction operator:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
dir1=${1:?} dir2=${2:?}

dir1_files=(${dir1%/}/*(DN:t))
dir2_files=(${dir2%/}/*(DN:t))

only_in_dir2=(${dir2:|dir1})

(($#only_in_dir2 == 0)) ||
  rm -rf -- $dir2/$^only_in_dir2
```

With `bash` and GNU utilities, the equivalent could be something like:

```
#! /bin/bash -
dir1=${1:?} dir2=${2:?}
export LC_ALL=C

chdir() {
  case $1 in
    (/*) CDPATH= cd -P "$1";;
    ("") echo >&2 invalid empty directory; false;;
    (*)  CDPATH= cd -P "./$1";;
  esac
}
list_files() (
  shopt -s nullglob dotglob # equivalent of zsh's ND
  chdir "$1" &&
    set -- * &&
    (($# > 0)) &&
    printf '%s\0' "$@"
)
    
comm -z13 <(list_files "$dir1") <(list_files "$dir2") |
  (chdir "$dir2" && xargs -r0 rm -rf --)
```

Yes, believe it or not, that `chdir` function is how you change to an arbitrary directory in POSIX shells and [what POSIX will recommend in the next revision of the standard](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1047#c3751).

Note that, in the `zsh` case, if `dir1` is not readable, all files in `dir2` will be deleted.

With the `bash` one, it will be the case if `dir1` is not readable *or not searchable* (as `cd` needs *search* permission).

If you wanted to bail-out in case of error when trying to build the list of matching files, you could do something like:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
dir1=${1:?} dir2=${2:?}
zmodload zsh/system || exit

ERRNO=0
dir1_files=(${dir1%/}/*(DN:t))
dir2_files=(${dir2%/}/*(DN:t))

if ((ERRNO)); then
  syserror -p "An error occurred when trying to read the directories: "
  exit 1
fi

only_in_dir2=(${dir2:|dir1})

(($#only_in_dir2 == 0)) ||
  rm -rf -- $dir2/$^only_in_dir2
```

Answer (score 0):

To correct your original solution:

1. Like @Kusalananda said, you should turn `"$directory1/*"` and `"$directory2/*"` into `"$directory1"/*` and `"$directory2"/*`, respectively or else the for loop will try to look for files literally named "`*`".
2. If I understand your goal correctly, the line `rm "$f2"` should be `rm "$f1"` otherwise the program will just remove the last file in `$directory2` that mismatched the `$f1`, when `$f1` is the file that should be deleted because it just mismatched all the files in `$directory2`.

With just these 2 fixes, your script should work (assuming `directory1` and `directory2` are assigned correct values.)

But like @Kusalananda said, you don't have to make another loop. I think @Kusalananda was suggesting you do something like this(taking out `echo`s and correcting already mentioned mistakes):

```
for f1 in "$directory1"/*
do
    # ls "$directory2"/$(basename "$f1") &>/dev/null
    # if [[ $? != 0 ]]
    # EDIT below from @Kusalananda
    if [[ -e "$directory2/$(basename "$f1")" ]]
    then
        rm "$f1"
    fi
done
```

Technically, it is another for loop (because I believe `ls` does a for loop behind the scenes), but it looks a lot cleaner. Sorry, if there's extra quotations. I'm not the best at knowing how those should be used.

Comment: Better to test with `if [ -e "$directory2/$(basename "$f1")" ]; then rm ...; fi` than to rely on `ls`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, `ls -d` (contrary to `[ -e`) would return true for broken symlinks. In any case, it should be `ls -d -- "$directory2/$(basename -- "$f1")"` (which would still fail on filenames that end in newline characters, `${f1##*/}` would be better and more efficient).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Fair enough. I assumed one just wanted to check whether the name was there or not.